# CSS: center content on resize

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a content area which is centered by `margin:0 auto` and has a `width` of `1280px`. when i resize my browser window only the content on the right side gets cut off if the browsers `width` gets below `1280px`. is there a way to keep the whole site always centered so the content area gets cut of left an right equally?

Comment: use percentage width instead of a hard value of 1280px. or a media query to change that number. the width of your container is 1280px and will not get greater nor smaller so that is why some of your content is cut off.

Comment: You should also be able to use both: width:1280px; max-width:100%; Also can use a media query to change width depending on screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try with a mediaquery in which you can center your fixed-width div , e.g.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNqXGW

```
div {
  background: #d8d8d8;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1280px) {
   main { 
       /* hide horizontal scrollbar */
       overflow: hidden; 
   }
   div {
       /* these properties cut your div equally both
          on left and right side */
       margin-left: 50%;
       -webkit-transform: translateX(-640px);
       -moz-transform: translateX(-640px);
       transform: translateX(-640px);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using media queries like @media for responsive design.

And if the content is an image, consider making it the background, and set `{background-position: center}`

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need to keep the content `width` fixed at `1280px` you can use some `jQuery` to correct the position via `margin` property on `window.resize` event:

```
$(this).resize(function(){
    var width =  $('#itemToKeepCentered').width();
    var windowWidth = $(this).width()
   $('#itemToKeepCentered').css('margin-left', (windowWidth-width)*0.5);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/urahara/oq4uj9q7/2/

> Note: `@media` `css` may be useful to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it very usefull for a web page but yes.. with a very little jquery you can make your container be in the middle when larger that the window width.

It is not that "right side gets cut off ", it's that at larger content that window width the scroll starts, and the scroll bar by default will always be at the left (or top if vertical).

so just use this to center the scroll:

```
$(function () {
    scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
});
```

here you have a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL01acry/)**

Edited: Won't work with manual resize... try resizing and then reload the page